# opensips add user error

Tags: mysql, opensips

I am getting below error while adding any user in opensips

> MySQL ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user
>   'opensips'@'localhost' (using password: YES) info: user 1234 already
>   exist

Please help me to resolve

Comment: Did you use any OpenSIPS tools, web interface, or is this just a MySQL console error? Apparently, this looks like a permissions problem (typically solved with the `GRANT` MySQL statement). Some more info would be great!

Comment: **root@osboxes:/home/osboxes# opensipsctl add 1234@192.168.1.4 1234                                                                                                             
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'opensips'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
INFO: user '1234@192.168.1.4' already exists**                                         I am using opensipsctl add user command on Ubuntu terminal. The thing is initial installation work fines i can add user but one I restart the PC this error comes up while adding any user.

Comment: Please check your MySQL access, by using console test commands such as `mysql -uopensips -hlocalhost -p<your_pass>`

Answer (score 0):

1234 user is already exist into mysql subscriber table. So it is not
allowing to add similar one again. Just delete the 1234 user from
subscriber table from kamailio database and then try again.

Answer (score 0):

It's 99% mysql level issue.

Check "etc/opensips/opensipsctlrc" file if it has right users and passwords for db.

Then try to create db with "opensipsdbctl create anydb"

Then try to use created db for manage opensips users.